# Setting the position of a View, as the user drags their finger

Tags: android, android-layout

A `View` has a [`getLeft()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLeft%28%29) method, but how do I `setLeft`?

I want to do this so that I can move a `RelativeLayout` as the user drags their finger sideways across the screen. It is the same size and width as the screen, so as it moves it will need to move off the edge of the screen.

I have experimented with the various animation classes, but I don't think this is what I want in this scenario.

I'm targeting phones rather than tablets, so this needs to work for API level 7.

Answer (score 4):

I usually do things like this with `View.offsetTopAndBottom()` and/or `View.offsetLeftAndRight()` and adjust the view position with each touch/scroll update.  Also make sure that the `View` you are trying to move around isn't inside a layout that will be restricting you from doing so.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks, this works but the `RelativeLayout` that is being moved also resizes, so that it still fits within the bounds of the screen. Is it possible to move it so that it does not resize, and instead moves off the edge of the screen?

Comment: This may be a product of the layout parameters you have set on the view your moving with respect to it's parent.  If something is set to `fill_parent` or `match_parent` it will try to attach itself of the outer bound of the parent view, even while it moves.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, so changed the width to `wrap_content`. The `RelativeLayout` still gets resized to fit in the confines of the screen.

Comment: I use (indirectly, through `ViewDragHelper`) these methods to drag a View inside a `LinearLayout`. The problem is that every time this LinearLayout `onLayout()` method is called, the position of the view is reset (see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865291/why-is-view-dragged-with-viewdraghelper-reset-to-its-original-position-on-layout). Is there any way to avoid this? (I don't have this type of problem when I drag a View by modifying its margins)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure if this is what you were looking for, but there is no `setLeft()` method or anything else that directly sets the coordinates. What I would try is getting the `LayoutParams` and setting the left manually; like so: `view.getLayoutParams().left = 123` I'm not confident that this will work because it may depend on what type of `ViewGroup` the view is in (ie. LinearLayout). Good luck!

Comment: Oh you might also want to try `view.requestLayout()` to refresh it after you set the coordinates.

Comment: `getLayoutParams()` returns a `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` object, which sadly does not have a `left` property

Comment: What type of `ViewGroup` is your view in? LinearLayout? If it is try type casting it `(LinearLayout.LayoutParams)getLayoutParams()`