# Using ViewDragHelper to vertical dragging and ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewdraghelper

i'm trying to achive this on my application: 
[youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6cRptd6XQAE&feature=youtu.be)

The goal is to have a ViewPager that can be dragged vertically but at the same time you can swipe the views inside of ViewPager, the problem is when i swipe inside of viewPagger horizantally the dragg resets to the inicial position

to achive what is in the video, i follow this [blog post](http://fedepaol.github.io/blog/2014/09/01/dragging-with-viewdraghelper/)

So i implemented a DraggerViewHolder that extends to a FrameLayout and then ViewDragHelper inside of it! all the code is at [github](https://github.com/danielgek/DraggableViewPager)

So, how can i make it stay on the same drag state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally i have manage to fix the problem(sort of because sometimes i still get the "bug").

You can see in the github repo(in the question) the commit with the fix, for more information about the solution see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865291/why-is-view-dragged-with-viewdraghelper-reset-to-its-original-position-on-layout)